# BigQuery SQL: do SELECT aliases have priority over FROM clause column names when used in GROUP BY clause?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a simple query that has the ambiguity regarding `col`:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR(col, 1, 4) AS col, 
       COUNT(*) AS nc
  FROM (SELECT 'test1' AS col
         UNION ALL
        SELECT 'test2' AS col) 
 GROUP BY col
```

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#ambiguous-aliases), the query validator should raise an error:

> Ambiguity between a FROM clause column name and a SELECT list alias in GROUP BY:
>
> ```
> SELECT UPPER(LastName) AS LastName
> FROM Singers
> GROUP BY LastName;
> ```
>
> The query above is ambiguous and will produce an error because LastName in the GROUP BY clause could refer to the original column LastName in Singers, or it could refer to the alias AS LastName, whose value is UPPER(LastName).

But the query executes successfully and provides the following result:

```
╔═══╦═══════╦══════╗
║   ║ col   ║ nc   ║
╠═══╬═══════╬══════╣
║ 1 ║ test  ║ 2    ║
╚═══╩═══════╩══════╝
```

It's clear from the results that GROUP BY clause recognizes `col` as an alias from the outer select (whole `SUBSTR` expression).

So here is my question, is it reliable enough behavior? Can I write my queries taking this into account and adapting my queries correspondingly?

Comment: . . I suspect the docs may be out-of-date.  This type of scoping issue is usually resolved by a hierarchy.  Obviously there is no specified hierarchy in this case (because aliases in the `group by` are no standard).  However, it makes sense to look first in the `select` and then in the tables.

Comment: Also, consider using `GROUP BY 1` to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That query is not really ambiguous. I understand the intent well, and BigQuery too.

Compare:

```sql
WITH Singers AS (SELECT "Sinatra" LastName UNION ALL SELECT "sinatra")

SELECT UPPER(LastName) AS LastName
FROM Singers
GROUP BY Singers.LastName;
```

with

```sql
WITH Singers AS (SELECT "Sinatra" LastName UNION ALL SELECT "sinatra")

SELECT UPPER(LastName) AS LastName
FROM Singers
GROUP BY LastName;
```

Both behave as I expected. If anything, the documentation is wrong here, and I've filled a ticket so it gets fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, if the documentation is wrong, the current behavior is exactly what I expected